# Comparing two Timestamps from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

i have one big dataframe as a .csv, which is updated over time.

I take the last 7 rows of this dataframe and search for a startpoint and an endpoint. To make sure, the startpoint i'm using is earlier, than the endpoint within this shortened dataframe, i would like to compare the two timestamps.
The problem is, i can only get them as a series object, which i can't compare via `<` or `>`

Is there a possibility to compare the two values?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(r'\Dataframe.csv')
df_tail = df.tail(10)
Start = df_tail.loc[(df['node']=='ns=4;i=560') & (df['Value;']==3)]['Timestamp']
Stop = df_tail.loc[df['node']=='ns=2;s=DistanceAbs']['Timestamp']
Start_df = (Start.to_frame()).reset_index(drop=True)
Stop_df = (Stop.to_frame()).reset_index(drop=True)
Start = Start_df["Timestamp"]

if Start_df["Timestamp"] < Stop_df["Timestamp"]:
    print('yes')
```

The shortend dataframe looks like this:

```
    Timestamp                   node                Value;
63  2020-12-16 12:03:07.831569  ns=4;i=560          1.0
64  2020-12-16 12:03:10.567988  ns=2;s=DistanceAbs  0.8871407871551859
65  2020-12-16 12:03:12.832312  ns=4;i=562          440.0
66  2020-12-16 12:03:13.831145  ns=4;i=560          2.0
67  2020-12-16 12:03:20.331216  ns=4;i=560          3.0
68  2020-12-16 12:03:27.330800  ns=4;i=560          0.0
69  2020-12-16 12:03:32.833464  ns=4;i=560          1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the first item of the Series with the `item()` method:

```python
Start = df_tail.loc[(df['node']=='ns=4;i=560') & (df['Value;']==3)]['Timestamp'].item()
Stop = df_tail.loc[df['node']=='ns=2;s=DistanceAbs']['Timestamp'].item()
```

You can then check you condition:

```python
if Start < Stop:
    print('yes')
```